# Get the integer value an attribute in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I have a string that could look like these:

```
"length=10, width=40, height=80"
"length=10, height=80, width=40"
"width=40, height=80, length=10"
```

What's a quick way to parse a string to get the value of width no matter where it is in the string? Note that it can come at the end of the string or in the beginning/middle followed by a comma. So in the above example, the function should always return 40.

Comment: You could use a regular expression:
`var width = /width=(\d+)/.exec("length=10, width=40, height=80")[1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for that.

For example:
`parseInt(/width=(\d+)/i.exec(input)[1])`

Or, the longer, more readable version:

```js
const input = "length=10, width=40, height=80";
const regex = new RegExp("width=(\\d+)", "i");

const result = regex.exec(input);

const width = parseInt(result[1]);
```

Alternatively, with a named capturing group:

```
const input = "length=10, width=40, height=80";
const regex = new RegExp("width=(?<width>\\d+)", "i");

const result = regex.exec(input);

const width = parseInt(result.groups.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use case for regular expressions.
You want to match `width=[0-9]+` but only capture the numeric part, so use a capturing group.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.